# Search form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have a form with two input fields, that should route to search.servicecity with the two input fields as parameter (service and city). How can I achieve to say, that by clicking the submit button, the input fields are used as the parameters?

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['search.servicecity',service,city]]) !!}
   <div class="row">
     <div class='col-md-5'>
       <input type="text" class='form-control form-control-lg' name="service" id="service" placeholder="activity" data-action="{{ route('search.autocompleteservice') }}"/>
        <div id='searchresultservice' style='text-align:left'></div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-5'>
        <input type="text" class='form-control form-control-lg' name="city" id="city" placeholder="city or zip" data-action="{{ route('search.autocompletecity') }}"/>
        <div id='searchresultcity' style='text-align:left'></div>
      </div>
      {{ Form::submit('Suchen', array('class'=>'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block col-md-2'))}}
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: When the form is submitted then the inputs will be a part of the $request. You can handle that in the controller. If you need to manipulate the form action, you could probably do that by overloading the submit method on-click.

Comment: So you mean, that I should call a route e.g. search.search, that does not need parameters but proves the $request data and then route to the search.servicecity with the parameters from the request?

Comment: I created a method called getSearchRequest that should now handle the the routing, but its saying Action path\SearchController@getSearchRequest not defined. I call it with this action:
{!! Form::open(array('action' => "SearchController@getSearchRequest")) !!}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have code similar to below. You would obviously need to validate your inputs before trusting anything from the client. You could easily add validation in the view also. The routes file could be routes.php depending on your version of laravel.

File: routes\web.php

```
Route::get('search/servicecity', 'SearchController@index')->name('searchServiceCityForm');
Route::post('search/servicecity', 'SearchController@process')->name('processServiceCity');
```

File:    app\Http\Controller\SearchController.php

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {    
      return view('search.ServiceCity');
  }
  public function process(Request $request)
  {
      $service = $request->input('service');
      $city = $request->input('city');

      /* Do something with data */

      return view(search.result, compact('service','city'));
  }
```

File:    resources\views\search\ServiceCity.blade.php

```
<html><head><title>Search for City and Service</title></head><body>
<form method="post" action="{{url('search/servicecity')}}">
 {{csrf_field()}}
 <div>
  <label for="Service">Service:</label>
  <input type="text" name="service">
 </div>
 <div>
  <label for="city">City:</label>
  <input type="text" name="city">
 </div>
</body></html>
```

File:    resources\views\search\Result.blade.php

```
<html><head><title>Result of Service City Search</title></head><body>
<div><span>Searched for service: {{ $service }}</span></div>
<div><span>Searched for city: {{ $city }}</span></div>
</body></html>
</html>
```